# How to get Cideko air keyboard working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, xorg, joystick

I have a Cideko air keyboard, which I got working in a previous ubuntu version by adding the following lines to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev joystick catchall"
        MatchIsJoystick "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```

After upgrading to 18.04 I thought it might be as simple as editing /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf to add the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput joystick catchall"
        MatchIsJoystck "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

... but that doesn't work.

If I cat /dev/input/event5 in a terminal it works OK (for the duration of the command).  Here is the output of input by id:

```
# ls -ltr /dev/input/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 15:23 usb-PixArt_USB_Optical_Mouse-mouse -> ../mouse1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 15:23 usb-PixArt_USB_Optical_Mouse-event-mouse -> ../event7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 15:23 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-event-kbd -> ../event3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 15:23 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-event-if03 -> ../event6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 15:23 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-if01-mouse -> ../mouse0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 15:23 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-if01-event-mouse -> ../event4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 15:23 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-if02-event-joystick -> ../event5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 15:23 usb-15c2_0036-mouse -> ../mouse2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6 Sep  9 15:23 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-if02-joystick -> ../js0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 15:23 usb-Microsoft_Wired_Keyboard_600-event-kbd -> ../event9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 15:23 usb-Microsoft_Wired_Keyboard_600-if01-event-kbd -> ../event15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 15:23 usb-15c2_0036-event-mouse -> ../event23
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 15:23 usb-046d_0825_7CD77CA0-event-if00 -> ../event22
```

So how do I get the air keyboard working permanently?